# JSON questionnaire structure

Tags: json

I am struggling to determine simple questionnaire structure in json
So test can have multiple sections,
Each section can multiple sub sections
Each sub section must have one or more questions
I checked syntax using JSONLint, but apparently I cannot use the same element (sub_section, ot question) twice for the same object. this is what i get:

```
SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'question' on line 13
```

this is the JSON I have created:

```
"test_sections": [{
"section": [{
    "identifier": "section1",
    "caption": "translate.section1",
    "sub_section": [{
        "identifier": "sub_section1",
        "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section1",
        "question": {
            "identifier": "question1",
            "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section1.question1",
            "question": "How are you?"
        },
        "question": {
            "identifier": "question1",
            "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section1.question1",
            "question": "How are you?"
        }
    }],
    "sub_section": [{
        "identifier": "sub_section2",
        "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section2",
        "question": {
            "identifier": "question2",
            "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section2.question2",
            "question": "How is your day?"
        }
    }]
}],
"section": [{
    "identifier": "section2",
    "caption": "translate.section2",
    "sub_section": [{
        "identifier": "sub_section1",
        "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section1",
        "question": {
            "identifier": "question1",
            "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section1.question1",
            "question": "What is the time now?"
        }
    }],
    "sub_section": [{
        "identifier": "sub_section2",
        "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section2",
        "question": {
            "identifier": "question2",
            "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section2.question2",
            "question": "What is your favorite pet?"
        }
    }]
}]
```

}]

Comment: The first `sub-section` has two `question` properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating the same key, name your key as a plural, and give it an array as value:

```
{
    "test_sections": [{
        "identifier": "section1",
        "caption": "translate.section1",
        "sub_sections": [{
            "identifier": "sub_section1",
            "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section1",
            "questions": [{
                "identifier": "question1",
                "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section1.question1",
                "question": "How are you?"
            }, {
                "identifier": "question1",
                "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section1.question1",
                "question": "How are you?"
            }]
        }, {
            "identifier": "sub_section2",
            "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section2",
            "questions": [{
                "identifier": "question2",
                "caption": "translate.section1.sub_section2.question2",
                "question": "How is your day?"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "identifier": "section2",
        "caption": "translate.section2",
        "sub_sections": [{
            "identifier": "sub_section1",
            "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section1",
            "questions": [{
                "identifier": "question1",
                "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section1.question1",
                "question": "What is the time now?"
            }]
        }, {
            "identifier": "sub_section2",
            "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section2",
            "questions": [{
                "identifier": "question2",
                "caption": "translate.section2.sub_section2.question2",
                "question": "What is your favorite pet?"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: I got it, so property name cannot appear twice (like sub_section) great, thank you!